# How to create value objects from struts form beans?

Tags: java, struts

I need to create value objects from struts form beans. Is it a good idea to use Bean Utils or create the VO manually?

Anyone faced any isues with bean utils?

Answer (score 1):

value object is not created by developer side but it is automatically created by struts framework software in which form bean class plays role to create it.

****Definition:**** when the huge data transfering from one layer to another layer which can be transfering whaen as individual value for multiple no. of times. it is recomended to combined all these values into a single value object and then transfer to another layer the special class of that single object which can store multiple values is calles values object

Answer (score 0):

I have never faced any issues in using BeanUtils. It is always a good idea to use BeanUtils to get this job done as we can avoid rewriting code for this.